# new to windows services and have questions

Tags: c#, exception, windows-services, spring.net

I am currently writing a windows service and normally used to writing web applications in c#. Therefore I have some questions that more experienced programmers of windows services may be able to answer.

How are exceptions normally handled in a windows service, logged to event viewer, text file etc?

Normally when I write a web application I use an installer with custom actions to install it. Can I create the same for a windows service and install it similarly?

Finally, anyone have experience as to how to hook up spring.net dependency injection in to a windows service?

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge gap between recoverable and unrecoverable errors. You can overcome recoverable ones but you cannot do unrecoverable. So for unrecoverable errors I would recommend persist your error and shut down your service. 
For recoverable ones you can continue you execution loop.
There is some more information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156288/exception-handling-best-practice-in-a-windows-service).
To log something to event log use EventLog class from the BCL library. More details on it in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Yes, you can make an installer for a windows service. Implementation is pretty much the same.
The tool I would recommend to look for installation while not in production is [installutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I made integration of windows service with AutoFac container. You have to instantiate and configure your container after start. Unfortunately I don't have any Spring specific experience, so if your question is about some specifics I have no clue on it. But if it's general question on DI container integration that shot it.
Just in case: there is some time limitation of service to start.